# How are vapor barriers, moisture barriers, and house wrap different?

Tags: hvac, insulation, waterproofing

I've read many discussions here and elsewhere talking about these three things with regard to insulation, energy efficiency, and siding installation. What are the differences and where are each used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Vapor Barriers

Vapor barriers prevent moisture in the air from moving between locations. This is important when considering the building envelope in a home.

Since humans produce a lot of moisture through daily activity and bodily functions, humidity tends to be higher indoors than out during the heating season. If this moisture migrates out through the walls and ceiling when it's cold outside, it will condense into liquid water or frost where it encounters the dew point temperature. This is bad for some obvious reasons. Rot, mold, and pests can result.

To prevent these problems, vapor barrier is usually installed toward the conditioned space in a home--typically over framing and just behind drywall. This keeps airborne moisture inside the heated space where it's less likely to condense.

Vapor barrier installed in homes is most commonly polyethylene sheeting in 4 mil thickness, though thicker sheet may be used where fire retardance is needed, for example, or where higher durability is important.

## Moisture Barriers

This term is often synonymous with *vapor barrier* but is sometimes used to contrast the permeable traits of house wrap with the water-blocking nature of impermeable sheeting. Common uses for moisture barriers are shower walls, roofs, and backyard ponds. [EPDM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPDM_rubber) and [PVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyvinyl_chloride) are materials used in these cases.

## House Wrap

House wrap, such as Tyvek<sup>™</sup>, is air-permeable membrane used under siding to reduce airflow, thus saving energy otherwise used to heat or cool a home while allowing moisture in the air to escape. It also prevents liquid moisture from passing into the wall due to leaks in siding.

House wrap is *not* a vapor barrier. In fact, serious problems can arise from using solid material like polyethylene sheeting as house wrap when a similar vapor barrier is installed to the interior. Moisture can become trapped between those barriers, leading to mold, decay, and other damage.

Comment: Be good to have coverage of air barrier (difference from vapor barrier) and mention of the passive house wraps, perm ratings, vapor barrier paint.

Comment: Calculating where the Dew point occurs in the wall structure is also important. should be outside the vapor barrier....

Comment: I haven't found such calculation to be necessary. I can imagine it is for non-standard insulation strategies, but not for cases where vapor barrier is inside all insulation. It's not important.